# Custom rsnapshot backup sequence

Tags: version, incremental-backup, rsnapshot

The goal is to maintain a very detailed incremental structure:

```
Daily      90
Weekly     52
Monthly    All (i.e. permanent record)
```

Problem is, a weekly uses the *last* daily, which will not create unless all dailies are present, so the weekly [and then also monthly] need to create by date, not by sequence.

How can rsnapshot manage this sequence?